# Change user role while user is logged on

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

Lets say there are two user roles defined in a Java EE web application

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Is it possible to change a users role while he is still logged in into the system? 
If I change the role from `admin` to `user`, any further calls of `"#{request.isUserInRole('admin')}"` should return `false`, as well as security constraint as defined via `@DeclaredRoles` etc. should take place immediately.

Authentification and authorization is realized via a JDBC Realm. I am able to change the user role in the underlying Database, so for the next login of the user, the new role(s) will be applied, but I want to change the users authorization(s) while he is still logegd in (and without forcing him to re-login)

I do have access to the users principal name and the users Session object, if this is might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean, *immediately*.  Do you want to recalculate the roles during a single request or for a next request?

Comment: @frifle For the next request would be sufficent.